# How correctly compare list item and variable in Sass

Tags: sass

In Sass I've got list and a variable:

```
$fontWeight: 500;
$fontWeightList: 200 300 400 500 700 800 1000;
```

and I iterate through it with this construciton:

```
@each $fontWeightItem in $fontWeightList {
    @if ($fontWeight == $fontWeightItem) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But condition in @if statement never evaluates to true and I don't understand why!

Comment: It should be. What are the statments in `//do something`?

Comment: It doesn't matter (it's just a pice of code that break everything). I want condition evaluates to true when $fontWeightItem and $fontWeight is equal.

Comment: Try without parentheses: `@if $fontWeight == $fontWeightItem` . It's working fine on `Sass 3.3.9`, compiled using ruby gem.

Comment: Oh, I realise where was error. You're right. (I just add in other part of code @ else which makes @ error appear).